# Mysql Join inner join left join Multiple Tables null on right table

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

how to display multiple tables in mysql, i want to display some data such as: table1.autono, table1.name, table1.date. table1 on right table i dont see data thank you for your help

```
SELECT 
table1.autono, table2.number_reg, table3.no_auto, table4.address, table5.name
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table5 ON table3.no_auto=table5.auto_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table2.number_reg=table3.no_auto
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table3.auto_no=table1.name
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY table2.number_reg
```

Comment: Please post your table structures and actual/expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could always use AS

```
$query = mysql_query(SELECT tbl.column AS 'tbl.column' FROM tbl AS tbl ... );
```

then iterate the values and sort

```
foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($query) as $col=>$val){
   list($tbl,$col) = explode('.',$col);
}
```

or use the `mysql_field_table()` and `mysql_field_name()` functions

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
$fieldCt = mysql_num_fields($query);
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($query); $i++){
    $field[$i] = mysql_field_table($query,$i).'.'.mysql_field_name($query,$i);
}
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++){
 foreach($field as $key=>$name){
   $row[$i][$name] = mysql_result($query,$i,$key);
 }
}
```

I didn't test it or anything, but that should map a query like that to an array `$row` with each entry being an array consisting of `tbl_name.field_name => value` entries.